# TransactionTooLargeException android Nougat bitmap

Tags: android, exception, bitmap, picasso

In one of my app sometimes appearing TransactionTooLargeException exception on Android 7.0/7.1 without exact point to source.

Using Android Emulator I found crash in activity with ViewPager, where every page have set from six images. And crash may happen in not predictable moment, usually after sliding some pages. Images are loading from files using Picasso library. I belive the resaon is hiding in Picasso processing loading files, but have no idea how to fix it.

Maybe rewrite code for using FragmentPagerAdapter but I'm not sure.

Below snippet of code, which processing image file:

```
           Picasso.with(context)
            .load(new File(card.getPath()))
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(target);
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466445/transactiontoolargeexception-only-on-nougat

Comment: I use ordinary PagerAdapter not FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: What is your targetSDKVersion?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 26